# Busqueda por columnas, definir una variable en Datatables 1.13

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo este codigo que da datatables para definir la variable `table` con el fin de hacer busquedas por cada columna:

La primera parte es la que inserta los input tipo texto, lo hace bien

```
$('#tblInvoice tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ' + title + 
    '">');
});
```

La otra parte del codigo, es la que envia la busqueda por cada columna, y es donde tengo el problema pues la variable `table` ya la tengo definida...

```
var table = $('#tblInvoice').DataTable();

table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;

    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that.search(this.value).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

he intentado colocar el codigo adentro junto con otros elementos de configuracion

```
var table = $('#tblInvoice').DataTable({
    table.columns().every(function() {
        var that = this;
        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that.search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Pero NO funciona, como lo puedo hacer en jquery o javascript?

Answer (score 1):

LLeve el codigo a una funcion y pasele la defincion de la tabla...

```
function SetupColumnSearch(table) {
    /* Setup column-level search input fields. */
    $(table.table().header()).find('th').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" 
        class="column_search form-control form-control-sm"/>');
    });

    table.columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        $('input.column_search', this.header()).on('keyup', function(e) {
            /* Avoid a DataTables bug where invisible columns show up */
            // if (e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode !== 10 && e.keyCode !== 13) return;
            if (column.visible()) {
                console.log(this.value);
                table.column(column.index()).search(this.value).draw(); // no funciona el draw() cuando serverSide=true TODO
                // table.ajax.reload(null, false);  // otra opcion TODO
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Funciono Perfecto!